# Vimeo api returning specified resource not found, but video available through browser

Tags: rest, curl, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am able to view video through browser but when tried to get metadata for same using curl, I get below response

> {
>       "error": "Something strange occurred. Please try again.",
>       "link": null,
>       "developer_message": "The specified resource doesn't exist.",
>       "error_code": 5000 }

Below is the curl url I am using.

curl -H "Authorization: bearer XXXX9eb82b84aX7XXXXXXca61eb3372" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.user+json;version=3.0,application/vnd.vimeo.video+json;version=3.4' https://api.vimeo.com/videos/XXXXXXX

For some security reasons, I can not copy actual token or video id here. Hoping to get some help here.

Thanks

Comment: You should contact Vimeo Support for help. If it can't be reproduced independently here, it's impossible for the Stack community to troubleshoot. https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: @TommyPenner: Hey thanks, i did same, and got to know its private video, hence above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a problem with your access token, make sure it has the "private" scope